# variable not assigning inside promise

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, mocha.js, puppeteer

Maybe I'm sleepy, but under what circumstances would the following occur?

```
let foo;

page
  .evaluate(() => {
    // return works... but not closure assignment

    // doesn't work
    foo = 'foo';

    // works
    return 'bar';
  })
  .then(bar => {
    console.log('foobar', foo, bar);
    // > foobar undefined bar
  });
```

This is occurring in a mocha test using puppeteer

update: the **exact entire code**

node 9.11.2

```
/* global describe, it, before, after */

const fs = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');
const assert = require('assert');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const sleep = require('shleep');

const extPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build');
const { name } = fs.readJSONSync(path.resolve(extPath, 'manifest.json'));

// Access chrome object in Extensions
// https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2878

describe('chrome extension', () => {
  let browser;
  let extensionPage;

  before(async function() {
    this.timeout(90 * 1000);

    // start puppeteer
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      args: [
        `--disable-extensions-except=${extPath}`,
        `--load-extension=${extPath}`
      ]
    });

    // poll instead of hope this is enough time?
    const EXT_LOAD_DELAY = 100;
    await sleep(EXT_LOAD_DELAY);

    const targets = await browser.targets();

    const extensionTarget = targets.find(
      ({ _targetInfo }) =>
        _targetInfo.type === 'background_page' && _targetInfo.title === name
    );

    const page = await extensionTarget.page();

    let foo;

    page
      .evaluate(() => {
        // return works... but not closure assignment

        // doesn't work
        foo = 'foo';

        // doesn't log
        console.log('foo', foo);

        // works
        return 'bar';
      })
      .then(bar => {
        console.log('foobar', foo, bar);
        // > foobar undefined bar
      });
  });

  it('should load', async () => {
    assert(true);
  });
});
```

screenshot of test

[image]

Comment: The above will certainly work if `evaluate`'s callback is called before `then`'s callback is called. Have you checked to make sure `evaluate`'s contract says that will happen? Edit: [Looks to me like it does](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args). The code above definitely will assign to the `foo` declared at the top. The real code you're having trouble with must be different (for instance, do you have a `foo` declared in the page function?).

Comment: Since you're not using an `async` function, the [tag:async-await] tag is irrelevant.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sure but it may have attracted promise experts :p

Comment: haha fair.. okay anyways, I guess I need to dig into the puppeteer / chromium source

Comment: Oh btw this is the exact code

Comment: You're claiming that the callback to `evaluate` runs, and then the `then` callback runs, and `foo` doesn't have the value `"foo"`? All due respect, I don't believe that, I believe it's observational error, or something in code you haven't shown. I hope you find the problem!

Comment: added full code and screenshot

Comment: Would you post your `package.json`?

Comment: Does `page.evaluate` run code in a different context? Like in a separate browser, with completely different variables?

Comment: sure, added package.json

Comment: @melpomene that sounds very likely. I'm unfamiliar with how code could jump contexts like that inside a single script

Comment: @melpomene - That seems likely.  Notice there is no output from `console.log('foo', foo);` in the console screen shot.

Comment: Well, it could call `.toSource()` on the function, send the string over to the browser, then `eval` it.

Comment: @melpomene super interesting... relevant: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1944

Comment: ... yep, that's exactly what it does: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/lib/ExecutionContext.js#L88-L89

Comment: thanks! that's wild.. had no idea that was a thing. if you make that an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @melpomene - I think you've found the answer (nice one!). I suggest posting it as an answer.

Comment: No time now; I'll come back to it later (if no one has posted an answer then).

Comment: This has nothing to do with promises. It's just that puppeteer (like many other headless browser frameworks) does not take a closure to its `evaluate` function - it takes a **function that will be stringified** and then injected into the loaded page as a script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `evaluate` method in puppeteer has no concept of variables that you have declared in your code either locally or globally. The function that you pass to the `evaluate` method are functions that are to be executed in the **page context** (ie. in your browser). Since `foo` is not declared in the page context, it cannot access it and therefore cannot update its value.

So to step through your code:

```
let foo;

await page.evaluate(() => {
  foo = 'foo';  // Since no variable foo is known to the evaluate method in the context of your page
                // this line , effectively, assigns a new variable called foo with a value 'foo' which
                // is then lost once the method has completed since its value is never returned.

  return 'bar'; // This value is returned from the method and is therefore retained below
})
.then(bar => {
  console.log('foobar', foo, bar);
  // foobar is output as expected since you've hardcoded it

  // foo is now referring to the global foo you declared earlier but since you have used `let` and not
  // assigned it any value, it is output as 'undefined'

  // bar is the value you returned from your 'evaluate' function and is therefore output as 'bar' as
  // expected in the console log.
});
```

If you wanted to use the `evaluate` to update your variable `foo` you would have to do it like this:

```
let foo;
foo = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return 'foo'
});
console.log(foo); // Now outputs 'foo' as expected
```

You can, however, inject variables into `evaluate` methods and update their values (if you wish), for example:

```
let foo = 'foo'
console.log(foo); // Outputs 'foo' as expected
foo = await page.evaluate((injectedFoo) => {
  return `new${injectedFoo}`;
}, foo);
console.log(foo); // Outputs 'newfoo'
```

So what happens here is you've injected the variable `foo` into the `evaluate` method by passing it as an argument at the end of the method declaration. The `evaluate` method now contains a variable (which I've called `injectedFoo` for clarity) which carries the original value of the `foo` variable.

I'm then returning the string `new` appended to the beginning to the `foo` variable string and output the final value of that in the console.

I hope this helps to explain how the `evaluate` method works!